# Howto disable the autohome feature in Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, home-directory, automount

On a newly installed Solaris 11.2, new users get their homedir automounted but I do not want this, I prefer to create them locally and statically. Of course I can completely disable the autofs service with "svcadm disable autofs" but I do want to keep automounting for the /net entries.
I already tried commenting out the "/home         auto_home       -nobrowse" from /etc/auto_master, then restarting the autofs service, it seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home directories for new users are local and their default location is `/export/home/<username>`. That means the `auto_home` facility which is about `/home` is not used.

Perhaps are you confusing this with the fact home directories are created when the `-m` option is used as independent ZFS datasets when their parent directory is already a dataset mount point. This is unrelated to `autofs` and just a `useradd` feature.

If you don't want this to happen, create their home directories yourself wherever you want and don't ask `useradd` to do it.

If you simply want to disable the `auto_home` feature, comment out the `auto_home` line in the `/etc/auto_master` file like this:

```
# /home   auto_home -nobrowse
```

and then restart the `autofs` service:

```
svcadm restart autofs
```

This will allow you to create regular directories under `/home`.

Comment: You have rightly understood that I was mixing things up; it is the creation of a new zfs that annoyed me. With regret I have resorted to leaving out the -m option from useradd.